# travis ci fails deploy on firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, travis-ci, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am trying to integrate travis ci on my firebase application to deploy automatically but it fails saying 401 error. Here is my .travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - '8'
deploy:
  provider: firebase
  token:
   secure: "BnzKtrzBaI/uLHoezYpBVqQ/VwhIyil...n0jAuBNrTI="
  message: build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER $TRAVIS_BRANCH/$COMMIT_HASH
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

I am not sure as what is going wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used the `provider` function in Travis CI before, but another option of deploying to Firebase hosting is to install `firebase-tools` and use the CLI.

```
language: node_js
node_js: 8

before_script:
  - npm install firebase-tools -g

script:
  - firebase deploy --only hosting --token "BnzK...rTI="
```

**-- Edit: More information on `Cloud Functions` and `Branch Filters`. --**

If you're deploying Cloud Functions as well, you'll need to install the `node_modules` on travis before you can deploy.

```
language: node_js
node_js: 8

before_script:
  - npm install firebase-tools -g
  - cd functions && npm install

script:
  - firebase deploy --only hosting,functions --token "BnzK...rTI="
```

If you want to only deploy when changes are made to the `master` branch you can add in this filter.

```
language: node_js
node_js: 8

before_script:
  - npm install firebase-tools -g
  - cd functions && npm install

script:
  - firebase deploy --only hosting,functions --token "BnzK...rTI="

branches:
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: I am not able to deploy to firebase with this way also. I get the following error
```
$ firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --non-interactive
=== Deploying to 'aradhana-api'...
i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
...
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'
Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
The command "firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --non-interactive" exited with 1.
```

Comment: Are you only trying to upload to Firebase Hosting, or are you also uploading Functions? The error is `Cannot find module 'firebase-functions' Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.`. Which means you need to do `cd functions && npm install` in the `script` prior to the deploy.

Comment: But this way it will try to deploy when I merge on any branch, isn't it? Travis recommends using only deploy provider. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Updated the response for you. Good luck!

Comment: "cd functions && npm install" is giving me an error:
   /home/travis/.rvm/hooks/after_use: line 7: printf: 0-next: invalid number
   $ npm ci 
   npm ERR! Unexpected string in JSON at position 1341

Any idea why?

Comment: also, consider using an environment variable (go to your repo's settings in travis) as not to version your token or expose it in the build logs. `firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"`